# How to mock Server Sent Events SSE aka EventSource?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, server-sent-events, eventsource, event-stream

In my angularjs application, I have functionality where I am using SSE in a following way. The code is in a third party library,

```
var source = new EventSource('usr_management.php');
source.addEventListener('newuser', function(e) {
   // business logic
});
```

Now I want to mock this in my `protractor` code I can use `httpBackend` to mock the request but what is the proper way to return appropriate `eventstream` response and trigger the event?